# Eclipse RCP Spring 3 Hibernate 4 class loading issue

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, eclipse-rcp

I am attempting to set annotation classess by subclass `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.
Bean xml is loaded fine with hibernate 3 until I change to hibernate 4 package. I got this error:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initia
lization - cancelling refresh attempt  

  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:7
8)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapable
BeanFactory.java:1032)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 24 more
```

My bean.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd" >

    <!-- Transaction Manager Definition -->
    <bean id = "transactionManager"        class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory"     ref = "sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"            class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    </bean>    

    <bean id="sessionFactory"         class = "customSessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource"         ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
               <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <!-- Cache Properties  -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
               </props>
            </property>
    </bean>
```

`customSessionFactory` class `setAnnotationClass` entity classes.
What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bundle imports the `org.hibernate` package. 
This may not have been required for hibernate 3.x.

In your MANIFEST.MF add `org.hibernate` to the `Import-Package:` section.

Comment: Thanks. I have already imported another bundle that had org.hibernate imported and with visibility:=reexport.  so org.hibernate should be there.  It might have to do something with class loader on bean  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext() that I used to load the beans.

Comment: Ok, after I change the adding Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered, ext, global on org.hibernate package MANIFEST.MF, i have no class not found error.  Though I got a problem with mapping.  Somehow annotation binding on inheritance is not working, even with @MappedSuperclass.